# How to create dataframe from below structure

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

I need to create DataFrame from below :

```
d={ "columns":"NAME1,NAME2,NAME3", 
"data":["MOOLA, MOOLA TEAM, MOOLA1","FIRST, FIRST, FIRST"] }
```

here data has two sets of records, I need data in the below format:

```
NAME1  NAME2       NAME3
MOOLA  MOOLA TEAM  MOOLA1
FIRST  FIRST       FIRST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Take a look at [**`pd.DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import pandas as pd
col=d['columns'].split(',')
data=[i.split(', ') for i in d['data']]
# data = ['NAME1', 'NAME2', 'NAME3']
#col = [['MOOLA', 'MOOLA TEAM', 'MOOLA1'], ['FIRST', 'FIRST', 'FIRST']]

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=col)

   NAME1       NAME2   NAME3
0  MOOLA  MOOLA TEAM  MOOLA1
1  FIRST       FIRST   FIRST
```

Comment: Glad it helped. My bad it was a typo. ;)